# How can I limit my Norway Spruce to one top (trunk)?

Tags: trees, pruning, tree-care, spruces

I have a [Norway spruce](http://plants.usda.gov/java/profile?symbol=PIAB) that is about sixty feet tall and is beginning a second trunk. I like them to have only one top, but this particular tree is not climbable. How do I control this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't want to seem to be against the "do-it-yourself" crowd, but at 60' tall the only safe answer is to hire an arborist.

Consider paying a professional to do the job of cutting off the second trunk versus the alternatives:

- possible personal injury while climbing the tree
- possible damage to your property, or someone else's property, from what falls from the tree
- not getting a clean cut and possibly adding an avenue of insect or fungal attack.